# How do I display most recent week items by default with WeekArchiveView?

Tags: python, django, django-1.3, django-class-based-views

I'm astonished by [how little](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/) documentation on class-based generic views there is.
Anything slightly more complex than a trivial sample has to get done through guesswork, trial and error.

I want to use [`WeekArchiveView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.dates.WeekArchiveView) to display a week's item list.

There's my `urls.py` entry:

```
url(r'^items/(?P<year>\d{4})/week/(?P<week>\d{1,2})/$', ItemWeekArchiveView.as_view())
```

When no `year` or `week` is specified, I get an error page.
I want them to equal today's year and week by default.

What is the right place for tweak here? Should I introduce another mixing and override a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Urls like `/items/` or `/items/2011/` wouldn't match your regexp because `\d{4}` means exactly 4 digits.

You probably should specify two another url entries for both cases:

```
url(r'^items/$', AchievementListView.as_view(
    year=str(date.today().year), week=str(date.today().isocalendar()[1])
    )),
url(r'^items/(?P<year>\d{4})/week/(?P<week>\d{1,2})/$', ItemWeekArchiveView.as_view()),
```

([Using `isocalendar` to get the week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python/2600878#2600878)).