# How do I paginate WeekArchiveView?

Tags: python, django, django-1.3, django-class-based-views, django-pagination

In continuation of [my struggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664590/how-do-i-display-most-recent-week-items-by-default-with-weekarchiveview) with [`WeekArchiveView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.dates.WeekArchiveView), how do I paginate it by week?

All I want is:

- to know if there is next / previous week available;
- in case there is, provide a link in the template.

I'd like it to also skip empty weeks.

[The source](http://google.com/codesearch#copo3dCwf5E/django/views/generic/dates.py) shows `get_next_day` / `get_prev_day` and `get_next_month` / `get_prev_month` are available, but nothing for weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is definitely interesting. Sure enough `MonthMixin` includes `get_next_month`/`get_prev_month` methods, and `DayMixin` includes `get_next_day`/`get_prev_day` methods. However, both YearMixin and WeekMixin have no functional equivalent in their definitions. Seems like a bit of an oversight on the Django team's part.

I think your best bet is to subclass either WeekArchiveView or BaseWeekArchiveView (if you may eventually want to change up the response format and don't want to have to re-implement your methods) and add your own `get_next_week`/`get_prev_week` methods. Then have your view inherit from your subclass instead. A simple modification of `DayMixin`s methods should be sufficient.

```
def get_next_week(self, date):
    """
    Get the next valid week.
    """
    next = date + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    return _get_next_prev_month(self, next, is_previous=False, use_first_day=False)

def get_previous_week(self, date):
    """
    Get the previous valid week.
    """
    prev = date - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    return _get_next_prev_month(self, prev, is_previous=True, use_first_day=False)
```

Comment: Can you please help me [figuring out the rest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665013/how-do-i-paginate-weekarchiveview/7667867#7667867)? We're almost there, I'm just looking for a clean way to make `previous_week` be `None` when there are no items before given week.

Comment: Oops! This was my fault. I set `allow_empty` to `True` so this is why I got those empty pages. Thanks a huge again!

Answer (score 2):

Taking [chrisdpratt's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665013/how-do-i-paginate-weekarchiveview/7667135#7667135) as basis, I created a class that provides the template with `next_week` and `previous_week`:

```
class BetterWeekArchiveView(WeekArchiveView):

    def get_next_week(self, date):
        """
        Get the next valid week.
        """
        next = date + timedelta(days=7)
        return _get_next_prev_month(self, next, is_previous=False, use_first_day=False)

    def get_previous_week(self, date):
        """
        Get the previous valid week.
        """
        prev = date - timedelta(days=7)
        return _get_next_prev_month(self, prev, is_previous=True, use_first_day=False)

    def get_dated_items(self):
        """
        Return (date_list, items, extra_context) for this request.
        Inject next_week and previous_week into extra_context.
        """
        result = super(BetterWeekArchiveView, self).get_dated_items()
        extra_context = result[2]
        date = extra_context['week']

        extra_context.update({
            'next_week': self.get_next_week(date),
            'previous_week': self.get_previous_week(date),
        })

        return result
```

This works perfect.