# NameError at week/2012/48/ global name '_get_next_prev_month' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-templates, python-2.7, django-views

i'm trying to get a weekarchive view to work but i'm getting the following error :

```
NameError at /archive/week/2012/48/
global name '_get_next_prev_month' is not defined 
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/archive/week/2012/48/
Django Version: 1.4.2
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
global name '_get_next_prev_month' is not defined
Exception Location: /job/views.py in get_next_week, line  79
Python Executable:  /jobenv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

this is the subclass my view inherits from:

```
class BetterWeekArchiveView(WeekArchiveView):

def get_next_week(self, date):
    """
    Get the next valid week.
    """
    from datetime import timedelta
    next = date + timedelta(days=7)
    return _get_next_prev_month(self, next, is_previous=False, use_first_day=False)

def get_previous_week(self, date):
    """
    Get the previous valid week.
    """
    from datetime import timedelta
    prev = date - timedelta(days=7)
    return _get_next_prev_month(self, prev, is_previous=True, use_first_day=False)

def get_dated_items(self):
    """
    Return (date_list, items, extra_context) for this request.
    Inject next_week and previous_week into extra_context.
    """
    result = super(BetterWeekArchiveView, self).get_dated_items()
    extra_context = result[2]
    date = extra_context['week']

    extra_context.update({
        'next_week': self.get_next_week(date),
        'previous_week': self.get_previous_week(date),
    })
    return result
```

and this is the view:

```
class week_archive(BetterWeekArchiveView):
   model=Job
   allow_future =True
   allow_empty=True
   paginate_by=12
   date_field='datemade'
   template_name='task/task_archive_week'

   def get_queryset(self):
       return Job.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```

i got this BetterWeekArchiveView() from [How do I paginate WeekArchiveView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665013/how-do-i-paginate-weekarchiveview)

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems i was missing an import, i found the definition of  _get_next_prev_month  in the source here:  [Django-source-file](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/views/generic/dates.py)
this  should be a minimal working example:

```
class BetterWeekArchiveView(WeekArchiveView):
    from django.views.generic.dates import _get_next_prev_month
    def get_next_week(self, date):
       """
        Get the next valid week.
        """
        from datetime import timedelta
        next = date + timedelta(days=7)
        return _get_next_prev_month(self, next, is_previous=False, use_first_day=False)

    def get_previous_week(self, date):
       """
       Get the previous valid week.
       """
       from datetime import timedelta
       prev = date - timedelta(days=7)
       return _get_next_prev_month(self, prev, is_previous=True, use_first_day=False)

    def get_dated_items(self):
        """
        Return (date_list, items, extra_context) for this request.
        Inject next_week and previous_week into extra_context.
        """
        result = super(BetterWeekArchiveView, self).get_dated_items()
        extra_context = result[2]
        date = extra_context['week']

        extra_context.update({
         'next_week': self.get_next_week(date),
          'previous_week': self.get_previous_week(date),
          })

         return result
```