# How to find out the week number given a date in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date in the format of `Fri Oct 02 19:52:02 +0000 2009`. I need to find the week number corresponding to this date in Python. I'm new to Python and I'm not aware of datetime having a functionality which allow me to find this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[time.strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) has the %U (week nr.) parameter.