# Week number for US format on Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to get week number with this simple script on python.

```
import datetime

t = datetime.date(2013,8,18)
print t.isocalendar()[1]
```

It returns 33 for ISO format, but for the US calendar it should be 34.
How can I get this week number for US format?

Comment: Did you see [How to get week number in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2608868)?

Comment: he want not just week number, he want US format week number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python North American work week number from datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658435/python-north-american-work-week-number-from-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. The ISO calendar is a great concept and may have some really good uses, but for business in the U.S. it just doesn't work well. I can't write an application that could potentially report days in the end of December as being in the next calendar year. The solution that works for me is:

```
from datetime import *
today = datetime.today()
print today.strftime("%U")
```

This will return the correct U.S. week number. The only caveat with this is that all days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0. Credit to Chaggster who gave a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5245186/95852) here: [How to get week number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python/2608868)

Comment: This answer gives incorrect results. The two answers here are correct:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658435/python-north-american-work-week-number-from-datetime

Comment: In the image below I compared many different methods and highlighted the two columns which match the North American system of work week numbering. You can see %U does not.
https://www.screencast.com/t/S6S7ufarnS9T  
Here is the code to replicate this: https://pastebin.com/QdtgUE5N