# Python North American work week number from datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, week-number

I am trying to get the work week number from a timestamp according to this system:

> USA, Canada, most of Latin America, Japan, Israel, South Korea, among
>   others, use a week numbering system (called North American in our
>   Calculator) in which the first week (numbered 1) of any given year is
>   the week which contains January 1st. The first day of a week is Sunday
>   and Saturday is the last.

https://www.calendar-12.com/week_number

Python's strftime method supports `%U` and `%W`, but neither of these match that system. Pandas also adds `%V` following ISO 8601 but this is not what is used in North America either.

Comment: Could you explain how the given options are not working for you? How are they different?

Comment: Also, take a look at this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/2600775/9225671

Comment: @Ralf That question asks about and has answers for week number according to ISO 8601, which as I mentioned in my question is not the standard in North America. As for how the builtin Python options are different, you can read their description here: http://strftime.org/. They just don't match the description in my question. I tried them all and compared, here's an example (2016/01/02 should be WW01): https://www.screencast.com/t/5lSOb7NRmsG

Comment: So basically what you want to achieve is the values returned by the `%U` option but incremented by 1 (so that the year starts at 1 instead of 0), is that correct?

Comment: @Ralf I tried that but it's still incorrect. Increment by 1 is the first step, but then you still have this issue: https://www.screencast.com/t/5r4jttvh (those should all be the same week). So I then have to replace 53 with 1. Then I found some years ended up with the final week being 54, so I instead had to do a replacement on the maximum within the previous year. And even after all that I found that `%U` starts at 1 for some years like 2017, so initially incrementing by 1 makes that whole year wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the code I used in one of my projects. It is based on North American week numbering system where the first week is the week that contains January 1st.

```py
from datetime import date

def week1_start_ordinal(year):
    jan1 = date(year, 1, 1)
    jan1_ordinal = jan1.toordinal()
    jan1_weekday = jan1.weekday()
    week1_start_ordinal = jan1_ordinal - ((jan1_weekday + 1) % 7)
    return week1_start_ordinal

def week_from_date(date_object):
    date_ordinal = date_object.toordinal()
    year = date_object.year
    week = ((date_ordinal - week1_start_ordinal(year)) // 7) + 1
    if week >= 52:
        if date_ordinal >= week1_start_ordinal(year + 1):
            year += 1
            week = 1
    return year, week
```

For example:

```py
>>> from datetime import date
>>> week_from_date(date(2015, 12, 27))
(2016, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's what I came up with... it would be nice if this was included in datetime or Pandas though

```
def US_week(ts):
    if pd.isnull(ts):
        return np.nan

    import datetime as dt
    U = int(ts.strftime('%U'))


    # If this is last week of year and next year starts with week 0, make this part of the next years first week
    if U == int(dt.datetime(ts.year, 12, 31).strftime('%U')) and int(
            dt.datetime(ts.year + 1, 1, 1).strftime('%U')) == 0:
        week = 1

    # Some years start with 1 not 0 (for example 2017), then U corresponds to the North American work week already
    elif int(dt.datetime(ts.year, 1, 1).strftime('%U')) == 1:
        week = U
    else:
        week = U + 1

    return week

def US_week_str(ts):
    week = US_week_str(ts)
    return "{}-{:02}".format(ts.year, week)
```