# Python get number of the week by month

Tags: python

Any one could help me please, How to get number of week by month in Python?

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
```

Input:

```
date1 = "2015-07-09"
date2 = "2016-08-20"
```

Output:

```
2015-07 : 4
2015-08 : 5
2015-08 : 4
....
2016-08 : 5
```

How to count number of the week by monthly from date1 to date2?

Comment: Do you mean which week of the month it is?

Comment: What does the input look like? A string? A datetime?

Comment: I want to get number of the week by monthly from date to date.

Comment: An example input and example output please

Comment: @AnandSKumar Please refresh my question again. Thanks!!!

Comment: You give the output, but what is the input?

Comment: I think that what he is trying to ask is how many weeks are there between date 1 and date 2. Is it @TeahbuthNhel?

Comment: @tomasyany: That makes sense, but what does "by monthly" mean?

Comment: Mean that, How many number of week in month?

Comment: Four then... Like every month.

Comment: You need to rephrase that, @TheavuthNhel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python

Comment: Thanks every one, please kindly refresh my question again.

Comment: Ok. I think your output is wrong because you put `2015-08` twice with differents values. Then, how can a month in a year have 5 weeks? (If I correctly understood what you are trying to say). That would mean 35 days..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to measure the number of full weeks between two dates, you could accomplish this with [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) and [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) like so:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
date1 = datetime.strptime("2015-07-09", dateformat)
date2 = datetime.strptime("2016-08-20", dateformat)
weeks = int((date2-date1).days/7)
print weeks
```

This outputs `58`. The divide by 7 causes the number of weeks to be returned. The number of whole weeks is used (rather than partial) because of `int` which returns only the integer portion. If you wanted to get the number of partial weeks, you could divide by 7.0 instead of 7, and ensure that you remove the `int` piece.

Comment: FYI, integer division in Python 3.x returns floats.

Comment: @AnandSKumar: Thanks, edited to support both. I've worked in 2.x for so long that I often forget 3.x exists...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date1 = "2015-07-09"
date2 = "2016-08-20"
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, '%Y-%m-%d').date()  
diff = d2 -d1
weeks, days = divmod(diff.days, 7)
```