# How to get the last work week of the last month in previous year in Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Today is 2nd of January, if using Python pandas, any ideas on how to get the previous workweek?

For example today is work week 201801, and previous week is 201752, any ways can find the previous workweek of today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Timestamp` and `Timedelta`

```
(pd.Timestamp.now()-pd.Timedelta('7 days')).strftime('%Y-%U')
Out[148]: '2017-52'
```

Comment: hi, sorry for that, I notice this
 a=dt.datetime.now()
currentWW=a.strftime('%Y%U')
will return 201800 for me, how to make sure first week of the year is start with 01?

Comment: @ShiJieTio you can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python