# Get week numbers for different dates coming in the given format python

Tags: python, date-conversion

I am getting a list of dates in the format

```
Date
20180223
20180120
20180201
```

---

I want to get the week numbers for these in a new column

```
Date        Week_num 
20180223       8 
20180120       3 
20180210       6
```

---

The code being used to get the date here is :

```
yyyymmdd= (dt.datetime.today()-timedelta(days=1)+timedelta(hours=5.3)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

I need help with getting the weeks for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get week number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python)

Comment: I am able get it for a fixed date or sysdate. But here I have different dates in a different pattern .

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert your date back to a [datetime.date()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) object:

```
>>> mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime("20180223", "%Y%m%d").date()
>>> mydate
datetime.date(2018, 2, 23)
```

datetime.date() has a [date.isocalendar()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar), which contains ISO year, ISO week number and ISO weekday:

```
>>> mydate.isocalendar()
(2018, 8, 5)
```

As you can see the second entry to the tuple is the weeknumber you are looking for.

```
>>> mydate.isocalendar()[1]
8
```

Comment: This works fine for one date i.e. 20180223 but I require a solution such that I get a conversion for df["Date"] as a whole for the entire column

Comment: That is a whole different question and was never stated in the original question. I suggest that you accept this answer, as it does exactly what you asked, and go try to find the answer to your next question for yourself first.

Comment: Also, you can feed the entries in your df['date'] into this answer one by one, by a loop of some sorts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new week column using .apply() and lambda to impact all values in a column.

```
df['week'] = df['existing_date_col'].apply(lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1])
```