# python AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'week'

Tags: python, datetime

I have a snippet of code that extracts year, month, week from a date. Year and month works but year-month and week both returns error like the one below:

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'week'
```

I imported the library like this:

```
import datetime
```

and called on the dt column using col.dt.year, col.dt.month, col.dt.to_period('M'),col.dt.week.

The first 2 works and last 2 doesn't. After searching similar questions I still couldn't get it run. I'm on pandas '0.23.4'. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to provide code. Without it, we can only say you are referencing `col.dt` as `datetime.datetime` as the error says.

Comment: I realized the issue is that it's a vDDDtype rather than date time, which comes with some known issues in extracting time intervals and the code requires reading ical. I tried to combine the ymd into a proper dt object df['dt']=pd.to_datetime(dict(year=df['Year'], month=df['Month'], day=df['Day'])) and then run
df['dt'].dt.week() but it's now returning TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Comment: try `df['dt'].dt.week` instead of `df['dt'].dt.week()`

Comment: that worked! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Per [How to get week number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2010, 6, 16).isocalendar()[1]
24
```

Adapted to your code (assuming `col.dt` is a `datetime`),

```
col.dt.isocalendar()[1]
```

Comment: pretty sure `col.dt` is [pandas.Series.dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html)

Comment: I think you're right; if `pandas.Series.dt` simply defers to `datetime.datetime` under the hood, then `isocalendar()` would still work; otherwise I guess an explicit `to_pydatetime()` call would be required...