# Control datetime.isocalendar()

Tags: python, datetime

Following answers to this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python`, I was using `datetime.isocalendar()`, and more specifically `datetime.isocalendar()[1]` to get the **week number**, for instance:

```
import datetime as dt
dt.date(2015, 10, 16).isocalendar()[1]
>>> 42
```

Which is fine at a glance, except that result is different from:

```
dt.date(2015, 10, 16).strftime('%W')
>>> '41'
```

One can argue that it is fine as long as the 1-week different between the 2 methos is consistent for all dates.

But a major issue strikes for some end-of-the year dates, for instance:

```
dt.date(2018, 12, 31).isocalendar()[1]
>>> 1

dt.date(2018, 12, 31).strftime('%W')
>>> 53
```

There is no way I would expect the `datetime.isocalendar()` method returns week #1 for Dec.31, 2018. Note, it seems that the coder have followed an [ISO standard](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/calendar/isocalendar.htm), see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html).

**How can I somewhat control the behavior?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO week has 52 or 53 full weeks. That is 364 or 371 days instead of the usual 365 or 366 days.

ISO uses a special algorithm. You can read more [here](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/calendar/isocalendar.htm). So it has advantages like all weeks have exactly 7 days and every week belongs to a single year.

Using one of the types depends on the tasks you solve.