# How to get today week no of year in django

Tags: django

i trying to get today week no of year 
    from datetime import datetime
    import datetime
    from time import strftime
    from dateutil import parser

```
today_date = strftime("%V")
today_week = parser.parse(today_date)
today_week = today_week.weekday()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get week number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use isocalender() from datetime.time, it returns a tuple which contains calender week at index 1.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2019, 6, 16).isocalendar()[1]
   24
```

Comment: actually its a static in my case user can select any date so need the week no of that day

Comment: then add data in it dynamically.

`def weeknumber(inputdate):
    return datetime.date( inputdate).isocalendar()[1]`