# How can I find the fiscal Week of date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with many dates: sample of the said list below

```
    Dates 
 1  2019-02-01 
 2  2018-03-10 
 3  2019-08-01 
 4  2020-02-07
```

I would like to have it so that if input a date, of any year I can get the week number.
However, the fiscal year starts on Aug 1 of any given year. 
I tried just shifting the date to Jan 1 but it's different for every year due to leap years.

```
data['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Dates'])
data['Week'] = (data['Dates'] - timedelta(days=215)).week
print(data)
```

how can I get a result similar to this one below

```
    Dates        Week
 1  2019-02-01   27 
 2  2018-03-10   32
 3  2019-08-01   1
 4  2020-02-07   28
```

-Note: the weeks are probably incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer ignores the fiscal year part of the OP. I am leaving the fiscal year start date calc to the reader but this will calculate the week number (where Monday is the start of the week) from an arbitrary start date.

```
from dateutil import relativedelta
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

NEXT_MONDAY = relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=relativedelta.MO)
LAST_MONDAY = relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=relativedelta.MO(-1))
ONE_WEEK = timedelta(weeks=1)

def week_in_fiscal_year(d: date, fiscal_year_start: date) -> int:
    fy_week_2_monday = fiscal_year_start + NEXT_MONDAY
    if d < fy_week_2_monday:
        return 1
    else:
        cur_week_monday = d + LAST_MONDAY
        return int((cur_week_monday - fy_week_2_monday) / ONE_WEEK) + 2
```

adapted from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62836069/15507998)

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a datetime, then call datetime.date(2010, 6, 16).strftime("%V")4

You can also use isocalendar which will return a tuple, as opposed to a string above datetime.date(2010, 6, 16).isocalendar()[1]

[How to get week number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python)