# What week of the month is it?

Tags: python, datetime, pendulum

pendulum v2.1.0 on macOS

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> d = pendulum.Date(2019, 12, 31)
>>> d.week_of_month
-46
```

Isn't new years day 2019 the week 5 of the month?

How to interpret week of the month result negative 46?

Comment: Look like a bug in pendulum library.

Comment: Yeah, probably something to do with incorrect usage of `datetime.date.isocalendar` within pendulum. I'm currently testing.

Comment: I guess there is already an issue regarding this.

Comment: @Pygirl, if so, why don't you link it here?

Comment: You can also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2608868/7941251) as a workaround. `isocalendar` returns the 1st week of 2020 due to a different definition of a "week".

Comment: A [github issue](https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/issues/455) about this.

Comment: for me it returns 5 on pendulum version 2.0.5. Which version are you on?

Comment: @Davo 1st line of the question

Comment: @SuperStormer missed it. Thanks

Comment: @Davo the regression appears to have occured because of [this commit](https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/pull/446/commits/07c39fffca5cd1eece455ea66cb9fb660fae7890).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use calendar:

```
import calendar
import numpy as np
calendar.setfirstweekday(6)

def get_week_of_month(year, month, day):
    x = np.array(calendar.monthcalendar(year, month))
    week_of_month = np.where(x==day)[0][0] + 1
    return(week_of_month)

get_week_of_month(2019,12,31)
```

---

**Output:**

```
5
```

---

This is what they use:

```
def week_of_month(d):
    first_day_of_month = d.replace(day=1)
    print(d.week_of_year,first_day_of_month.week_of_year)

    return d.week_of_year - first_day_of_month.week_of_year + 1

week_of_month(d)
```

---

Bug is here

```
first_day_of_month.week_of_year gives --> 48
```

---

Earlier they were using this:

```
import math
def week_of_month(d):
        return int(math.ceil(d.day / 7))
```

which gives correct output

Comment: Why does pendulum say -46 tho?

Comment: the problem is with the isocalendar