# How to convert Datetime ("2020-09-27 07:14:01.114051200") to week number?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to find the week number of a date column in my datasets. The date is in the format `"2020-09-27 07:14:01.114051200"`. However I could not convert to week number.

I tried the below code:

```
date=mydate.strftime("%W")
```

I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: It works for me, what is the result are you getting?

Comment: Check this out- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python

Comment: Note that `mydate` should be an instance of `date`/`datetime` and not `str`

Comment: getting this error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first convert your date in string form to a `datetime` object.  Then you can ask for the week number from that object.

```
import datetime
datestr = "2020-09-27 07:14:01.114051200"
mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr.split('.')[0] , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date=mydate.strftime("%W")
print(date)
```

Result:

```
38
```