# How do I add together all numbers from the same week into a list?

Tags: python, list, datetime, strptime, strftime

I've been googling for answers for about 2 days now and I'm still stuck.

I have a huge list of dates and numbers like this:

```
 1.1.2018 0:00;2590
 3.1.2018 1:00;2530
 4.2.2018 2:00;1700
 6.2.2018 3:00;2340
 18.3.2018 4:00;1800
 15.4.2018 5:00;2850
 ...
```

And I need to add all numbers together that have the same week number and return total of numbers in a week like this:

```
0;0
1;549730
2;645010
3;681320
4;677060
5;698450
...etc
52;576280
53;81640
```

This is my code so far, I've separated the dates and numbers in their own lists but not sure how to go on from here. I'm supposed to use strftime %W somehow, but don't know how.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    file = open("2018Electricity.txt", "r")
    line = file.readline()
    time_list = []
    electricity_list = []
    total = []

    for i in file:
        time = i.strip().split(';')[0]
        electricity = i.strip().split(';')[1]
        time_list.append(datetime.strptime(time, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'))
        electricity_list.append(electricity)
        
    file.close()

main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to get week number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python)

Comment: What does each element in each line represent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple dictionary and run it sequentially.

```
import datetime
def solution():
    data = [
        "1.1.2018 0:00;2590",
        "3.1.2018 1:00;2530",
        "4.2.2018 2:00;170",
        "6.2.2018 3:00;2340",
        "18.3.2018 4:00;1800",
        "15.4.2018 5:00;2850"
    ]

    result = {} # store in a dictionary

    for date in data:
        day = int(date.split(".")[0])
        month = int(date.split(".")[1])
        year = int(date.split(".")[2][0:5])
        week = datetime.date(year, month, day).isocalendar()[1]
        if week not in result:
            result[week] = 0
        result[week] += int(date.split(";")[1])
    return result

result = solution()
for week, value in result.items():
    print(f"{week};{value}")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a list instead? And also so it returns 0;0 & and week 53 as well? Because right now it returns weeks 1-52 and week 1 added week 53's numbers to it.

Comment: please have a look at [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) ;-)